# VS2010 freezes when loading a new MVC 3 solution status bar reads, "Adding jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.11 to project..."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

If I start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application with a Internet Application Project Template, VS freezes and the bottom status bar reads, "Adding jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.11 to project..."
I don't know what to do at this point.

I'm running:
Windows Server 2008

VS2010 Ultimate 
  Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
  Microsoft .NET Framework
  Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
  Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
  Windows Azure Tools   Version 1.4
  Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 v1.4.40727.1601

Answer:
I don't know exactly what the problem was, but now it is fine.

First, I start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application with a Blank Template and that started up without freezing. Then, I closed that solution and tried to open my original solution, the one that froze, but there was no *.sln file.  So, I opened the project file and that created a solution file and I saved that in the solution folder and everything is good.  In the end, I did have to add the System.Web.Mvc Reference to the project in order to get it to build.  No freezing so far.  I hope someone finds this and saves them some time.

Comment: got the same issue. you solved this?

Comment: i got the same issue aswell, any solution to this?

Comment: I have this issue w/ VS2010 haging on the jQuery message. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: I don't know exactly what the problem was, but now it is fine.

First, I start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application with a Blank Template and that started up without freezing. Then, I closed that solution and tried to open my original solution, the one that froze, but there was no *.sln file. So, I opened the project file and that created a solution file and I saved that in the solution folder and everything is good. In the end, I did have to add the System.Web.Mvc Reference to the project in order to get it to build. No freezing so far. I hope someone finds this and saves them some time.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create a separate new solution with the desired new MVC project, and copy the new project subtree and the packages folder (if not already there) to the old/existing solution. Then manually add the new project to the solution, e.g. by editing the sln file. At least that worked for me.

I noticed that my solution file had "zombie" build configs for a project that had been removed from the solution (the four build configs' GUID was non-existent in the sln file). Not sure this has anything to do with the problem, but it might be worth trying should the problem arise again: try to remove any zombie build configs from the sln file and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the VirtualBox Host-Only network adapter seems to have worked for me. Perhaps it tries to connect to the network through this when getting checking for packages.